# Overriding constructor arguments in Spring

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

Say I have two beans (where `BeanA` properties are immutable, requiring constructor injection):

```
<bean id="beanA1" class="BeanA">
  <constructor-arg type="ServiceA" ref="serviceA" />
  <constructor-arg type="ServiceB" ref="serviceB" />
  <constructor-arg type="ServiceC" ref="serviceC" />
  <constructor-arg type="boolean" value="false" />
</bean>

<bean id="beanA2" class="BeanA">
  <constructor-arg type="ServiceA" ref="serviceA" />
  <constructor-arg type="ServiceB" ref="serviceB" />
  <constructor-arg type="ServiceC" ref="serviceC" />
  <constructor-arg type="boolean" value="true" />
</bean>
```

Since they share everything but the boolean, I wanted to merge them as such:

```
<bean id="beanA1" class="BeanA">
  <constructor-arg type="ServiceA" ref="serviceA" />
  <constructor-arg type="ServiceB" ref="serviceB" />
  <constructor-arg type="ServiceC" ref="serviceC" />
  <constructor-arg type="boolean" value="false" />
</bean>

<bean id="beanA2" parent="beanA1">
  <constructor-arg type="boolean" value="true" />
</bean>
```

However, this doesn't seem to be working

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'beanA2' defined in class path resource [context.xml]: Could not resolve matching constructor (hint: specify index/type/name arguments for simple parameters to avoid type ambiguities)
```

Any way to do this with constructor injection?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do what you are trying to achieve with the Constructor Dependency Injection because in the case of the `beanA2` you are calling a constructor with a single boolean parameter.

However, you can achieve what you want if you change the injection from a constructor-based to a setter-based DI:

```
<bean id="beanA1" class="BeanA">
  <property type="ServiceA" ref="serviceA" />
  <property type="ServiceB" ref="serviceB" />
  <property type="ServiceC" ref="serviceC" />
  <property type="boolean" value="false" />
</bean>

<bean id="beanA2" parent="beanA1">
  <property type="boolean" value="true" />
</bean>
```

For further details, you can read more at the Spring documentation[Bean definition inheritance](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s06.html)

Comment: Thanks arkanoid! That's what I was afraid of... Unfortunately, the bean in question is immutable, so setter injection cannot be used.

Comment: @levantpied You are welcome. Hope to be useful in a useful way next time!! ;)

Answer (score -1):

Current exception telling you that there is no constructor with only one `boolean` value. It is not clear why you need constructor injection, you could try just to set needed property by it name to `false`.

Comment: Thanks Vitalii - it's actually clear why I need constructor injection from the first sentence :) "where BeanA properties are immutable, requiring constructor injection"

Comment: sorry, I missed that )

Comment: No worries :) Driving in a fast lane!